# Приложение вылетает сразу после запуска

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.readyfo.smartnotes/com.readyfo.smartnotes.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "priority"
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3622)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3662)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2896)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1611)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:171)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6633)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "priority"
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:608)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:643)
        at com.readyfo.smartnotes.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:61)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1356)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7192)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3597)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3662) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2896) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1611) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:171) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6633) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

---

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentEventListener{

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentEventListener{    
private List<Note> notes = new ArrayList<>();

    ListView listView;
    ImageView priority;
    TextView theme;
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor cursor;
    SimpleCursorAdapter noteAdapter;
    int numPriority = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        priority = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.edTrafficLights);
        theme = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edThemeNotes);
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void setArrayListNote(ArrayList<Note> notes) {
        for (int i = 0; i < notes.size(); i++) {
            this.notes.add(0, notes.get(i));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // открываем подключение
        db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        cursor =  db.rawQuery("select * from "+ DBHelper.TABLE_NOTES, null);

        String[] priority = new String[] {DBHelper.KEY_PRIORITY};

        for (int i = 0; i < priority.length; i++){
            numPriority = Integer.parseInt(priority[i]);
        }

        if (numPriority == 1){
            ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.edTrafficLights);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.traffic_light_red);
        }
        else if (numPriority == 2){
            ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.edTrafficLights);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.traffic_light_yellow);
        }
        else if (numPriority == 3){
            ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.edTrafficLights);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.traffic_light_green);
        }
        else {
            ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.edTrafficLights);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.traffic_light_not_priority);
        }

        String[] notes = new String[] {DBHelper.KEY_THEME};

        noteAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.main_fragment,
                cursor, notes, new int[]{ R.id.edThemeNotes}, 0);
        listView.setAdapter(noteAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        db.close();
        cursor.close();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.new_note, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.edWriteNewNote:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewNote.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: открывайте подключение к БД только 1 раз в onCreate, из onResume весь код вообще нужно вынести в onCreate. Смотрите на ваши переменные, почему priority это и String и ImageView? DBHelper.KEY_PRIORITY - это строковая константа, зачем делать из нее массив и гулять по ней циклом?

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
>   "priority"

Все началось с этой строки:

```
String[] priority = new String[] {DBHelper.KEY_PRIORITY};
```

Здесь вместо того, чтобы использовать Cursor и достать данные из БД по полю (используя db.query или db.rawQuery), вы определили строковый массив из 1 переменной **DBHelper.KEY_PRIORITY** которая объявлена как "**priority**"

Далее эту строку переводите в число!

```
numPriority = Integer.parseInt(priority[i]);
```

Получили ошибку, и приложение закрылось.

В коде еще куча ошибок, поэтому опишу их сразу:

1. Открывать БД нужно в onCreate, и вообще весь код из onResume нужно перенести в onCreate. Иначе приложение будет работать не стабильно, при каждом срабатывании onResume.
2. **parseInt** - часто приводит к вылетам, если приложение должным образом не тестировалось. Используйте try, или проверяйте данные в строке, перед их использованием.
3. Лучше не использовать одинаковые имена переменных в разных частях кода, особенно если на начальном этапе уже имеете проблемы с кодом. Поиск по переменным: **priority** и **notes**.

Answer (score 0):

В отчете об ошибке четко сказано:

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "priority"

для андроида другая библиотека

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper